# Additional custom build directories .targets file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++-2008

I have defined some custom build rules to use a custom version of Qt (DAZ Studio SDK) in my Visual Studio Projects using the ones from https://code.google.com/p/xr-qt-msvc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmsvc-10.0 .

I am currently struggling since the line

```
<CommandLineTemplate>$(DAZSDKDIR)\bin\$(Platform)\moc.exe [QtMocNoWarnings] [QtCoreLib] [QtShared] [QtThread] [QtUnicode] [QtLargeFile] [QtKeywords] [QtOpenGLLib] [QtNoDebug] [QtGuiLib] [Inputs] -o$(IntDir)%(QtMocFilename).cpp 
&amp;&amp; cl.exe $(IntDir)%(QtMocFilename).cpp [QtCommandLine] /c /Fo"$(IntDir)%(QtMocFilename).obj"</CommandLineTemplate>
```

(Notice the cl.exe called on the output MOC)

The fact is that I am not able to pass to cl.exe the include directories I have specified using AdditionalIncludeDirectories.

Is there any way to pass them to the cl compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Instead of using "Additional Include Direcotries", the user must use the V++ Directories tab.